# Reading a csv file in batch mode using pyflink from local system

Tags: python, csv, apache-flink, pyflink

I was trying to read an established csv file while writing a pyflink job. I was using filesystem connector to get the data but after executing execute_sql() on the ddl and later doing query on the table I was getting an error which explains that it isn't able to fetch the next result. I am unable to resolve this error. I have checked the csv file and it's fully correct and working with pandas but here I don't why it isn't able to fetch the next line. For reference please find the attached code.

```
from pyflink.common.serialization import SimpleStringEncoder
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream.connectors import StreamingFileSink
from pyflink.table import EnvironmentSettings, StreamTableEnvironment, BatchTableEnvironment
from pyflink.dataset import ExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.table import TableConfig, DataTypes, BatchTableEnvironment
from pyflink.table.descriptors import Schema, OldCsv, FileSystem
from pyflink.table.expressions import lit
import pandas as pd
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction
import os
```

```
## CREATE THE ENVIRONMENT

# create a blink batch TableEnvironment
env_settings = EnvironmentSettings.new_instance().in_batch_mode().use_blink_planner().build()
table_env = BatchTableEnvironment.create(environment_settings=env_settings)
```

```
#connector for ingesting the data
source_ddl = """
                CREATE TABLE MyUserTable (
                        timestamp_info TIMESTAMP(3),
                        column_a FLOAT,
                        column_b FLOAT,
                        column_c INT,
                        ) WITH (
                          'connector' = 'filesystem',          
                          'path' = 'file:///Users/abc/Projects/temp.csv', 
                          'format' = 'csv'

                        )"""


#connector for data output/sink
sink_ddl = """
                CREATE TABLE results (
                            timestamp_info TIMESTAMP(3),
                            score FLOAT)
                            WITH (
                                'connector' = 'filesystem',
                                'path' = 'file:///Users/abc/Projects/results.csv',
                                'format' = 'csv'
                            )"""
```

```
#make the table corresponding to the schema mentioned
source_table = table_env.execute_sql(source_ddl)
sink_table = table_env.execute_sql(sink_ddl)

#convert the sql table to table API
table_path = table_env.from_path("MyUserTable")

# execute SELECT statement
table_result2 = table_env.execute_sql("SELECT timestamp_info,column_a FROM MyUserTable")
table_result2.print()
```

**Error that was coming :-**

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner (file:/Users/avil.a/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyflink/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.12.2.jar) to field java.lang.Class.ANNOTATION
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
+-------------------------+--------------------------------+
|          timestamp_info |                       column_a |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------+
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "local_implementation.py", line 51, in <module>
    table_result2.print()
  File "/Users/avil.a/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyflink/table/table_result.py", line 219, in print
    self._j_table_result.print()
  File "/Users/avil.a/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1285, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/Users/avil.a/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyflink/util/exceptions.py", line 147, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/Users/avil.a/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o46.print.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to fetch next result
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultIterator.nextResultFromFetcher(CollectResultIterator.java:109)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultIterator.hasNext(CollectResultIterator.java:80)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.sinks.SelectTableSinkBase$RowIteratorWrapper.hasNext(SelectTableSinkBase.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl$CloseableRowIteratorWrapper.hasNext(TableResultImpl.java:350)
    at org.apache.flink.table.utils.PrintUtils.printAsTableauForm(PrintUtils.java:149)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl.print(TableResultImpl.java:154)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to fetch job execution result
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultFetcher.getAccumulatorResults(CollectResultFetcher.java:169)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultFetcher.next(CollectResultFetcher.java:118)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultIterator.nextResultFromFetcher(CollectResultIterator.java:106)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2086)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultFetcher.getAccumulatorResults(CollectResultFetcher.java:167)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$2(MiniClusterJobClient.java:117)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApplyNow(CompletableFuture.java:680)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApplyStage(CompletableFuture.java:658)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenApply(CompletableFuture.java:2158)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.getJobExecutionResult(MiniClusterJobClient.java:114)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultFetcher.getAccumulatorResults(CollectResultFetcher.java:166)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:118)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:233)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:224)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:215)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:669)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:89)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:447)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:305)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:212)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:158)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to deserialize CSV row.
    at org.apache.flink.formats.csv.CsvFileSystemFormatFactory$CsvInputFormat.nextRecord(CsvFileSystemFormatFactory.java:257)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.csv.CsvFileSystemFormatFactory$CsvInputFormat.nextRecord(CsvFileSystemFormatFactory.java:162)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.InputFormatSourceFunction.run(InputFormatSourceFunction.java:90)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:263)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
    at java.sql/java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(Timestamp.java:196)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.csv.CsvToRowDataConverters.convertToTimestamp(CsvToRowDataConverters.java:250)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.csv.CsvToRowDataConverters.lambda$createNullableConverter$ac6e531e$1(CsvToRowDataConverters.java:113)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.csv.CsvToRowDataConverters.lambda$createRowConverter$18bb1dd$1(CsvToRowDataConverters.java:98)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.csv.CsvFileSystemFormatFactory$CsvInputFormat.nextRecord(CsvFileSystemFormatFactory.java:251)
```

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp format was not matching with the time index in the csv file. Further while reading the csv file like this it will take the first row and try to parse it and if your csv file had headers in it then it will give error because it expected TIMESTAMP format at first but got a string which can't be parsed to the required format. Hence, ensure that the csv file had no headers in it.