# pyflink winerror 2 get_gateway()

Tags: apache-flink, python-3.8, pyflink

Following a script on stackOverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66578509/reading-a-csv-file-in-batch-mode-using-pyflink-from-local-system) as described by the link with the only change of the data in the sense I would like to evaluate the simple usage of pyflink in order to analyze if the installation of it works.You can see below the system and in order to install it I use pip -m install apache-flink into a virtual environment with python3.8.4. In order to install flink itself I used docker and I import the images of pyflink/playgrounds:1.10.0. Below is there the only the part taken from link that I modify

```
source_ddl = """
                CREATE TABLE MyUserTable (
                        column_a INT,
                        column_b INT,
                        
                        ) WITH (
                          'connector' = 'filesystem',         
                          'path' = 'file:///Users//code/examples/input.csv ', 
                          'format' = 'csv'

                        )"""


#connector for data output/sink
sink_ddl = """
                CREATE TABLE results (
                            score INT)
                            WITH (
                                'connector' = 'filesystem',
                                'path' = 'file:///Users//code/examples/output.csv',
                                'format' = 'csv'
                            )"""

#make the table corresponding to the schema mentioned
source_table = table_env.execute_sql(source_ddl)
sink_table = table_env.execute_sql(sink_ddl)

#convert the sql table to table API
table_path = table_env.from_path("MyUserTable")

# execute SELECT statement
table_result2 = table_env.execute_sql("SELECT column_a FROM MyUserTable")
table_result2.print()
```

The error is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\flink1.py", line 15, in <module>
    env_settings = EnvironmentSettings.new_instance().in_batch_mode().use_blink_planner().build()
  File "C:\Users\landr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyflink\table\environment_settings.py", line 214, in new_instance
    return EnvironmentSettings.Builder()
  File "C:\Users\landr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyflink\table\environment_settings.py", line 48, in __init__
    gateway = get_gateway()
  File "C:\Users\landr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyflink\java_gateway.py", line 62, in get_gateway
    _gateway = launch_gateway()
  File "C:\Users\landr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyflink\java_gateway.py", line 106, in launch_gateway
    p = launch_gateway_server_process(env, args)
  File "C:\Users\landr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyflink\pyflink_gateway_server.py", line 221, in launch_gateway_server_process
    return Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, preexec_fn=preexec_fn, env=env)
  File "C:\Users\landr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\landr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child   
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Impossibile trovare il file specificato
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error today. I put a print statement into `pyflink_gateway_server.py` to show the command being passed. I found that the call was to a version of Java that no longer existed on my computer (I’d upgraded it).

The fix was to ensure that JAVA_HOME pointed to a valid Java installation.